# How to parse Object in preference with swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, object

```
"byte_package" =     (
                {

            attribute = "<null>";
            balance = "1517268.75";
            "changed_at" = "2016-05-12 16:57:01";
            "created_at" = "2016-05-10 11:03:37";
            description = "2.3 GB BYTE Package. Expires in 30 days.";
            expiration = "2016-06-09 00:00:00";
            "expired_flag" = 0;
            id = 930;
            "package_flag" = 1;
            rid = "BYTE-00002";
            title = "2.3 GB";
            type = BYTE;
            used = "894456.00";
            "used_flag" = 0;
            value = "2411724.75";
        }
```

I want to parse the upper Object in array using preference.
How to parse Object data using preference? And then Object data storing to CoreData. How to solve this problem?. Please Help me.

Comment: preference mean NSUserDefault ?

Comment: yes, I mean NSUserDefault. @NitinGohel

Comment: Get Array object with  " byte_package" from user default and check if count > 0 then get [array objectAtIndex:0]

Comment: Many Duplicate answer: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=store+array+in+nsuserdefaults+ios+swift&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=-4g1V6bQC6rT8geCgaGIDg